# How do you film your DS screen?

Tags: nintendo-ds, recording

I've seen lots of gameplays where they are filming just the DS screen, **picture below**, How? [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways that I know of:

- People are playing DS games on an emulator, and thus it would be as easy as just recording your screen.
- Using a capture card. [Here's](http://3dscapture.com/) a website which shows the capture card in use (and sells them).

Comment: Do you know how to film ONE program?

Comment: @Jont [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) is a very popular and free software that a lot of people use to record their screen.