# How to film from a Nintendo DSi

Tags: recording, nintendo-dsi

[Similar question, but is for Nintendo DS, not DSi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147295/how-do-you-film-your-ds-screen)

My first search found [this](https://forum.speeddemosarchive.com/post/nintendo_dsdsl_dsidsi_xl_capture_device_new.html) but half of the links no longer exist or are out of stock and then the rest don't appear to support DSi.

To clarify, I am not looking to use the DSi as a video camera - I wish to get high quality audio and video output from DSi games

It could well be the case that this is not possible, but if there is a solution that would obviously be preferable.

Comment: Just so you know, everything that works with the original DS should also work with the DSi, except if it requires a GBA cartridge slot (because the DSi doesn't have one).

Comment: @Nolonar Except it isn't true.  This [DS capture board version](http://3dscapture.com/ds/index.html) clearly states the DS capture board doesn't work with DS Lite or DSi, only the original DS.

Comment: @Nelson. Ah, I forgot the DSi doesn't have a USB port. My bad.